# Autodesk Map Server 2013 GetFeature request failing without providing enough of a clue

Tags: wfs, getfeature

This is a Autodesk Map Server support question more then a GIS question...

I am trying to buffer features using Map Server 2013 but receiving the following error:

```
**An exception occurred in FDO component. String does not represent a valid filter.**
```

But I cannot see anything wrong with the  request below.  The capabilities service boasts the following spatial capabilities (note *Intersects* is listed):

```
<ogc:Spatial_Capabilities>
  <ogc:GeometryOperands>
    <ogc:GeometryOperand>gml:Envelope</ogc:GeometryOperand>
    <ogc:GeometryOperand>gml:LineString</ogc:GeometryOperand>
    <ogc:GeometryOperand>gml:Point</ogc:GeometryOperand>
    <ogc:GeometryOperand>gml:Polygon</ogc:GeometryOperand>
  </ogc:GeometryOperands>
  <ogc:SpatialOperators>
    <ogc:SpatialOperator name="BBOX" />
    <ogc:SpatialOperator name="Contains" />
    <ogc:SpatialOperator name="Crosses" />
    <ogc:SpatialOperator name="Disjoint" />
    <ogc:SpatialOperator name="DWithin" />
    <ogc:SpatialOperator name="Equals" />
    <ogc:SpatialOperator name="Intersects" />
    <ogc:SpatialOperator name="Overlaps" />
    <ogc:SpatialOperator name="Touches" />
    <ogc:SpatialOperator name="Within" />
  </ogc:SpatialOperators>
</ogc:Spatial_Capabilities>
```

This is the actual request which is failing:

```
<GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS"
version="1.1.0" maxFeatures="500" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
  <wfs:Query typeName="ns63133509:ST_WASTE_CONTAINER" SRSNAME="EPSG:26910">
    <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <Intersects>
        <PropertyName>Geometry</PropertyName>
        <Polygon srsName="EPSG:26910" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
          <exterior>
            <LinearRing>
              <posList>489272.945 5457256.531 489271.98426402 5457246.7764839
              489269.138976626 5457237.39682838 489264.518480615
              5457228.75248835 489258.300339059 5457221.17566094
              489250.723511651 5457214.95751939 489242.079171618
              5457210.33702337 489232.699516101 5457207.49173598 489222.945
              5457206.531 489213.190483899 5457207.49173598 489203.810828382
              5457210.33702337 489195.166488349 5457214.95751939
              489187.589660941 5457221.17566094 489181.371519385
              5457228.75248835 489176.751023374 5457237.39682838
              489173.90573598 5457246.7764839 489172.945 5457256.531
              489173.90573598 5457266.2855161 489176.751023374 5457275.66517162
              489181.371519385 5457284.30951165 489187.589660941
              5457291.88633906 489195.166488349 5457298.10448062
              489203.810828382 5457302.72497663 489213.190483899
              5457305.57026402 489222.945 5457306.531 489232.699516101
              5457305.57026402 489242.079171618 5457302.72497663
              489250.723511651 5457298.10448062 489258.300339059
              5457291.88633906 489264.518480615 5457284.30951165
              489269.138976626 5457275.66517162 489271.98426402 5457266.2855161
              489272.945 5457256.531</posList>
            </LinearRing>
          </exterior>
        </Polygon>
      </Intersects>
    </Filter>
  </wfs:Query>
</GetFeature>
```

The DescribeFeatureType looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://fdo.osgeo.org/schemas/feature/ns63133509"
xmlns:fdo="http://fdo.osgeo.org/schemas" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
xmlns:ns63133509="http://fdo.osgeo.org/schemas/feature/ns63133509"
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="ST_WASTE_CONTAINER"
  type="ns63133509:ST_WASTE_CONTAINERType" abstract="false"
  substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature">
    <xs:key name="ST_WASTE_CONTAINERKey">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//ST_WASTE_CONTAINER" />
      <xs:field xpath="PRIMARYINDEX" />
    </xs:key>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="ST_WASTE_CONTAINERType" abstract="false"
  fdo:geometryName="Geometry">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="PRIMARYINDEX">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:int" />
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="COMPKEY" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="30" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="FID" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:double" />
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="UNITID" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:maxLength value="30" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Geometry" type="gml:AbstractGeometryType"
          fdo:hasMeasure="false" fdo:hasElevation="false"
          fdo:srsName="UTM83-10" fdo:geometricTypes="point"
          fdo:geometryTypes="point multipoint" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

UPDATE: Error log isn't very helpful but does provide a stack trace:

```
<2012-11-26T14:50:00>   9400        10.42.100.93    WfsUser
 Error: An exception occurred in FDO component.
        String does not represent a valid filter. 
 StackTrace:
  - MgFeatureServiceHandler.ProcessOperation() line 83 file d:\build\ims2013\build_52.8\ent\os\server\src\services\feature\FeatureServiceHandler.cpp
  - MgOpGetWfsFeature.Execute() line 208 file d:\build\ims2013\build_52.8\ent\os\server\src\services\feature\OpGetWfsFeature.cpp
  - MgServerFeatureService.GetWfsFeature() line 2017 file d:\build\ims2013\build_52.8\ent\os\server\src\services\feature\ServerFeatureService.cpp
  - MgServerFeatureService.SelectFeatures() line 462 file d:\build\ims2013\build_52.8\ent\os\server\src\services\feature\ServerFeatureService.cpp
  - MgServerSelectFeatures.SelectFeatures() line 306 file d:\build\ims2013\build_52.8\ent\os\server\src\services\feature\ServerSelectFeatures.cpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "answer" is to add a space after  (e.g.  490051).  AutoDesk has been made aware of this issue.